# Cypress - How to use if statement with contains

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

so I have to use `cy.contains`  to find the element I want, but all I can find online is how to use if() with `cy.find` or `cy.get` if there a way to do this with contains?

Example code:

```js
if(cy.contains('div.name', 'Test 1').length > 0) {   
            //Type in name
            cy.get('input.newName').click().type('Test 1'); 
            cy.wait(2000);
            //Click Add Name
            cy.get('div.createNewName> a').click();
            cy.wait(2000);
        }
```

What I am trying to do there is:

```js
if(Name doesnt exist){
    Create it
}
```

I'm not sure if I have explained myself too well, if any more clarifications are needed feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do like this:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('div.name:contains("Test 1")').length > 0) {
    //Element Found
  } else {
    //Element not found
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me, although I changed .length > 0  to .length === 0 as I just needed to check if the element existed and do x if it didn't, I didn't need to do anything if it did.

Answer (score 3):

The general pattern for this would be as follows:

```js
const element = Cypress.$('div.name:contains(Test 1)')
if (element.length > 0) {   
  ...
```

Make sure the DOM is stable when you run this code, there is no retry built in as there is with `cy.contains()`

If the code inside `if()` is creating the name, then maybe the logic would be

```js
const element = Cypress.$('div.name:contains(Test 1)')
if (element.length === 0) {   
  // not found so create it
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, the `body` is the default with `Cypress.$()` - you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this

```js
cy.get('div.name').then($div => {
  const found = $div.find(':contains("Test 1")')
  if (found.length === 0) {
    // create...
  }
})
```